# ruby sorbet cannot run on CentOS7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, centos7, sorbet

I catch following error when try to run srb tc  on CentOS7.

```
/home/web/app/vendor/bundle/gems/sorbet-static-0.4.4388-x86_64-linux/libexec/sorbet: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /home/web/app/vendor/bundle/gems/sorbet-static-0.4.4388-x86_64-linux/libexec/sorbet)
```

CentOS7 has glibc 2.17 and it seems too risky to update this library as it is one of most important libs. Can I use my current OS with sorbet anyhow?

My configuration:

```
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
```

```
Name        : glibc
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.17
Release     : 260.el7_6.4
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be reported as a bug to https://github.com/stripe/sorbet/issues .

The fix is likely to either:

- compile releases on an system with older glibc and rely on backward compatibility;
- ship version of glibc with Sorbet;
- statically link against musl.

Comment: I did it actually. https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/948#issuecomment-508511569